# Drupal: update.php error

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm copying my Drupal installation to another folder and I've copied the related database.

When I run update.php on the new copy I get the following error:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/updateError.png

should I disable some modules.. or is something about Drupal core ?

(I'm using version 6.16)

I've flushed all caches and the website is offline.

thanks

Comment: Are you changing drupal version as well?

Comment: no, I'm just copying all files and database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to log in  to run update.php...
actually I'm also wondering how could you run update.php without being logged as administrator O_O

For the error... looking at the line reported in the error:

```
list($module, $version) = array_pop(reset($_SESSION['updates_remaining']));
```

you can see the use of `$_SESSION` array;

Probably you don't have any php sessions if you are not logged in...

Comment: I've always run update.php without log in on my websites. And it always worked! Thanks for the explaination. Useful to know.